# Get value of CheckBox in GridView, Bit Datatype, asp.net

Tags: gridview, types, checkbox, bit

1. I am beginner and question or syntax may be silly.
2. I have drawn a grid view having based on a SqlDataSource query.
3. Converted a status field into Bit.
4. a checkbox is automatically created.

now how can i get the value of checkbox on SelectedIndexChanged.

```
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel_Entry.Visible = true;
        int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        String vDescr = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("BitStatus");
        Response.Write(chk.ToString()+vDescr);}
```

### System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

error is shown.
please help in this regard.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Line 68: Response.Write(chk.ToString()+vDescr); Line 69: Line 70:

Comment: The error raises just when you reach one of these lines, on which of them it raises? 66 or 67 or .....? I think it should be raised on line 67 ?

Comment: yes i think it is because ... once we want to try to print the value or apply some if condition, it gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everybody...I have found the solution.

`CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Controls[0];
if (chk.Checked) { Response.Write("yes"); } else { Response.Write("no"); }`
it is working fine.
findcontrol() works if we are using some asp:template itemtemplate etc.

Answer (score 1):

when you add a control dynamically , you should load the control again and it will not list in control tree.for finding it you can use a loop to find it like it is said in this post
[Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net)

Also look at this post too: it seems useful [ASP.Net FindControl is not working - How come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799655/asp-net-findcontrol-is-not-working-how-come)