# Panel.FindControl not working

Tags: panel, findcontrol

In my content page, I am having a `Telerik:RadWindow` which will be used as a Popup
I have an asp:Panel inside this findingPopup like below.

```
<Telerik:RadWindow ID="findingPopup" runat="server" Modal="true" VisibleStatusbar="false" VisibleTitlebar="false" VisibleOnPageLoad="false" AutoSize="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pCheckListType" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</Telerik:RadWindow>
```

Inside this Panel I dynamically add another asp:Panel which contains an HTML table and a DropDownList. It gets generated perfectly fine. I viewed the page source which is as below:

```
<div id="ctl00_cpBody_findingPopup_C_pCheckListType">               
<div id="ctl00_cpBody_findingPopup_C_pnlGenerated_51">
    <table id="ctl00_cpBody_findingPopup_C_tblGenerated_51" class="NoStyle">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="ctl00$cpBody$findingPopup$C$ddList_51" id="ctl00_cpBody_findingPopup_C_ddList_51">
                        <option selected="selected" value="1" title="lt-master.app-tkn-flg">Face to Face</option>
                        <option value="2">Mail</option>
                        <option value="3">Phone</option>
                        <option value="4">Internet</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is, I am not able to find the DropDownList using the Panel.FindControl as well as I looked at [FindControlRecursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799655/asp-net-findcontrol-is-not-working-how-come) question. But I do not get the DropDownList even with starting the root element as Page. Could any one help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I guess I know the reason. The dynamically created elements get disappeared while postback. Any one has any suggestions on how to get the value of dropdownlist when the button is clicked?

Comment: Re-create the controls on postback.

Comment: I was recreating the controls on post back. The problem was, I was not assigning any ids. Actually, the above block was inside a asp:Panel. During post back, the inconsistent dynamic ids were created for this Panel and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually recreating the controls. The problem was with the Ids. I had to assign them some id numbers which should remain the same while post back. That fixed my problem.