# Getting repeater item checkbox values when calling command from footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Have following repeater control with a list of checkboxes:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItemList" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemName").ToString() %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdItem" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemId").ToString() %>' />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="lbtnDel_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete selected items from this list?')"></asp:LinkButton>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and following back code to handle the lbtnDel_Click event:

```
    protected void lbtnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptItemList.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl("chkItem");
            HiddenField hd = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("hdItem");

            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                var tc = new ItemController();
                tc.DeleteItem(Convert.ToInt32(hd.Value));
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL());
    }
```

When I select a checkbox and click delete, the code finds the checkbox but reads it as unchecked so doesn't delete the item.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for awesomeness.  I hadn't thought of using a hidden field in the repeater for storing values.  If I could up-vote more, I would.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but are you doing data binding in every page load? Try binding only on `!IsPostBack` 
Whenever I have any issues like this, it's usually because the Page Load has caused the repeater to re-bind and killed all the current state

Comment: Lol, school boy error. Yeah the databind was being performed in the page load and killing the state. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a repeater inside an update panel. So the only control in the RepeaterItem was a DataBoundLiteralControl

This worked for me:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpLists.Items)
                {

                    if (item.Controls.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataBoundLiteralControl dbLt = item.Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl;
                        if (dbLt != null)
                        {
                            var controlCollection = this.ParseControl(dbLt.Text);
                            HtmlInputCheckBox cbInclude = (HtmlInputCheckBox) FindControl(controlCollection, "cbIncludeList");
                            if (cbInclude != null)
                            {
                                if (cbInclude.Checked)
                                {
                                    //your code here 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I had to create a recursive method to for FindControl, something about it not working if its not part of a page. *Shrug*
See here [ASP.Net FindControl is not working - How come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799655/asp-net-findcontrol-is-not-working-how-come)

```
private Control FindControl(Control parent, string id)
        {
            if (parent.ID == id)
                return parent;

            if (parent.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (Control childControl in parent.Controls)
                {

                    if (childControl.ID == id)
                        return childControl;

                    if (childControl.HasControls())
                        return FindControl(childControl, id);
                }

            }

            return null;
        }
```